# jQuery LazyLoad Alternative (minus the scrollbar code)

Tags: jquery, html, css, lazy-loading

Hey, What I would like is to use the jQuery plugin: [LazyLoad](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload)

But, rather than trigger the event on Window Scroll - I would like to trigger it when the 
elements come into view.

(I have no scroll bars on my site, so scroll bars are **not** an option).

Help me before I have no hair left.

**EDIT: Ok, so I got it to work - SORT OF - it only seems to work vertically and ONLY WITH THE OVERFLOW SHOWING! ***

Comment: http://www.netdoctor.co.uk/health_advice/facts/hairloss_male.htm
about the hair issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to set a timer and repeatedly check for image visibility. Or you can make the `tracker` function public method and then call it from the outside if something alters.

Change LazyLoad to something like this:

```
// ...
var elements = this;
if ("scroll" == settings.event) { // <-- you may want to remove conditional block
     var tracker = function(event) {  // <-- give it a name
        var counter = 0;
        elements.each(function() {
            if ($.abovethetop(this, settings) ||
                $.leftofbegin(this, settings)) {
                    /* Nothing. */
            } else if (!$.belowthefold(this, settings) &&
                !$.rightoffold(this, settings)) {
                    $(this).trigger("appear");
            } else {
                if (counter++ > settings.failurelimit) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
        /* Remove image from array so it is not looped next time. */
        var temp = $.grep(elements, function(element) {
            return !element.loaded;
        });
        elements = $(temp);
    };

    (function repeat(){              
      tracker(); // <-- so you can use it here
      if (elements.length) 
        setTimeout(repeat, 100); // <-- check every 100ms
    })();
}
// ...
```

Comment: Hi, cheers for this. It seems that this is still binding the visibility to the window scroll method? I have no scroll bars on my site.

Comment: you can remove event binding and only define `tracker` function there. But the idea is the same. See my update.

Comment: I removed the `if ("scroll" == settings.event) {` line and the corresponding `}`, but it does nothing. I've initialised it with `$('img.link').lazyload();` - no errors, no functionality...

Comment: *I only showed you the door, you need to walk through it.* :) works then?

Comment: haha, sort of - I've updated my question. It only works when `overflow` is not `hidden`

Comment: can you post an example on jsbin.com?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/egope - jQuery isn't included, I've put LazyLoad in the javascript alongside the `$(document).ready` function. Styles are there (no images, so best of luck)

Comment: please correct the urls of the images or set `<base>` + some `<style>` would be good too :)

Comment: unfortunetely my client forbids me to upload the images until the site is live. I've added in what little styles I could let go... sorry to be a pain

Comment: press `new revision` if you make a change, in order to save the updated version

Comment: I get the feeling that this question is going to be buried as well :(